# How to manage errors with bokeh library (Python + JavaScript) and show them on the user interface?

Tags: javascript, python, exception, bokeh, custom-exceptions

I am working in a [Bokeh Server Application](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#building-bokeh-applications) using the Python library **"Bokeh"** and I usually get two types of errors.

- **JavaScript errors** on the Chromium console
- **Python errors** on the server side, they appear in the Tornado logger. Bokeh works with the Tornado Web Server

What I could achieve is to create manual exceptions inheriting the `Exception` class in python. In this way I can write custom messages and run some actions when the error is raised with this class.

```python
class ManualException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

        # some actions

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(
            'MANUAL ERROR\n' + self.value
        )
```

But if any other exception occurs then I do not know how to capture them to run some custom actions. I have tried this:

```python
try:
    n = 9 / 0
except Exception:
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    raise ManualException('ZERO ERROR').with_traceback(tb)
```

Here I have to catch any error manually and I raise them with my manual created class, then both appear in the python logger. Is this the proper way to do this?

```
2017-09-04 17:08:58,872 Error running application handler <bokeh.application.handlers.directory.DirectoryHandler object at 0x0000023E2435C208>: 'MANUAL ERROR\nZERO ERROR'
File "main.py", line 11, in <module>:
n = 9 / 0 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "[...]\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    n = 9 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "[...]\lib\site-packages\bokeh\application\handlers\code_runner.py", line 125, in run
    exec(self._code, module.__dict__)
File "[...]\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise ManualException('ZERO ERROR').with_traceback(tb)
File "[...]\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    n = 9 / 0
exceptions.ManualException: 'MANUAL ERROR\n'ZERO ERROR'
```

Anyway I want avoid this because I want to show all kind of errors to the user, even if I do not use `try-except` to capture exceptions.

On the other hand if a python error happens, a JavaScript message is shown. So I think the best option is to override some JavaScript method to run some custom js code. How could I achieve this? Is this achievable?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got [an answer in other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62475924/4891717). Some listeners can be added to the window in order to get the JavaScript error messages

> You can handle it as an event listener on window object.
>
> ```
> window.onunhandledrejection = function(event) {
>   console.warn(`UNHANDLED PROMISE REJECTION: ${event.reason}`);
> };
>
> window.onerror = function(event) {
>   console.warn(`UNHANDLED ERROR: ${event.message}`);
> };
> ```
>
> Or also like this:
>
> ```
>  window.addEventListener('error', function(event) { ... })
> ```
>
> You can read more about the `unhandledrejection` event on the [MDN web docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event) and the `onerror` event on the [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)